# How to pass whole file to perl script?

Tags: perl, stdin

I want to have a Perl script that receives a file and do some computation based on it.

Here is my try:

Perl.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $book = <STDIN>;

print $book;
```

Here is my execution of the script:

```
./Perl.pl < textFile
```

My script only prints the first line of textFile. Who can I load all textFile into my variable $book?

I want the file to be passed in that way, I do not want to use Perl's open(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a value from a file handle to a scalar pulls it one line at a time.

You can either:

- use a `while` loop to append the lines one by one until there are none left *or*
- set `$/` (to `undef`) to change your script's idea of what constitutes a line. There is an example of the latter in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) (read it as it explains best practises for changing it).

Comment: I got your idea, but how can I indicate the end of file is reached it this is my loop?
while(1) {
    $book = <STDIN>;
    print $book;
}

Comment: my $book; while(<STDIN>) { $book .= $_; } print $book;

Comment: Alternative: `my $book = join '', <>;`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `Path::Class` for easy. It is a wrapper for many file manipulation modules.

For your purpose:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Path::Class qw/file/;

my $file = file(shift @ARGV);
print $file->slurp;
```

You can run it by:

```
./slurp.pl textFile
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is in the Perl FAQ.

[How can I read in an entire file all at once?](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once?)